# reactjs chain filtering an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a function that will chain filter the data

```
const [arrayData, setArrayData] = useState([]);
const array = [...arrayData];
const [readyData, setreadyData] = useState([...arrayData]);
  const finalData = (params) => {
    array.push(params);
    setArrayData(array);
    setreadyData(array);
  };

const filterData = (types) => {
    let filteredData = readyData.filter((data) => {
      return data.types.some((type) => types.includes(type.type.name));
    });
    dispatch({ type: "FINAL_DATA", payload: filteredData });
    setreadyData(filteredData);
  };
```

I have `arrayData` as the default value, and `readyData` as the data I'm working on for the filter event.

My objective is to create a chain filtering function, but the problem is after the `readyData` got filtered once, it's impossible to do another filter since the data is not complete as the default one.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `readyData` is derived from `arrayData`, and `types`, it would be easier to save `types` as a state, and use `useMemo` to get `readyData`. Whenever `readyData` changes (accept mount) use `useEffect` to dispatch the `FINAL_DATA` action. Use `setTypesData` instead of `filterData` to update the `typesData`, and recalculate `readyData`...

Example (not tested):

```
const mount = useRef(false);

const [arrayData, setArrayData] = useState([]);
const [typesData, setTypesData] = useState([]);

const readyData = useMemo(() =>
  // filter arrayData if typesData is not empty
  typesData.length ? arrayData.filter(data =>
    data.types.some(({ type }) => typesData.includes(type.name))
  ) : arrayData
, [arrayData, typesData]);

useEffect(() => {
  // avoid dispatching on mount
  if(!mount.current) {
    mount.current = true;
    return;
  }

  dispatch({ type: "FINAL_DATA", payload: readyData });
}, [dispatch, readyData]);

// use setTypesData instead of filterData
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement it in my code but, I got some error says ```Cannot access 'readyData' before initialization```

Comment: Fixed. Try now.